# Open source CSS button library

Tags: library, css, user-interface

I need a free library with pre-made buttons: changing color when you hover over the buttons, good design etc. One that is compatible with jQuery.

Like for example this SE button

[image]

Or like these buttons: https://fdossena.com/?p=html5cool/buttons/i.frag